# Why plt.fill_between in matlpotlib is not filling properly

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying shade between two line, but it isn't working in python

```
a_seq  [0.  0.5 1.5 2.  2.5 3.  3.5 4.  4.  4. ]
l1 = [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0]
l2 = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0]
plt.plot(a_seq)
plt.plot(l1)
plt.plot(l2)
plt.fill_between(
    a_seq,
    l2,
    l1,
    alpha=0.2,
)
```

plt.show
I'm getting the shade out of the lines
[image]

Any idea to fix this up?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are trying to fill the area between l1 and l2. The first argument of `plt.fill_between` should be the x-values of the two lines between which you want to fill. [Read here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html). For your case of l1 and l2, as you are using the plot function, the x-values are simply given by `np.arange(0,len(l1))`. This works as shown below.

```py
a_seq = [0.,0.5, 1.5 ,2.,  2.5, 3.,  3.5, 4.,  4.,  4. ]
l1 = [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0]
l2 = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0]
plt.plot(np.arange(0,len(a_seq)),a_seq)
plt.plot(l1)
plt.plot(l2)
plt.fill_between( np.arange(0,len(l1)), l2, l1, alpha=0.2)
plt.show()
```

#### Fill area between l1, l2

[image: Fill area between l1, l2]

If you want to fill between some other pair of lines, you only need to make a few small changes.

```py
plt.plot(np.arange(0,len(a_seq)),a_seq)
plt.plot(l1)
plt.plot(l2)
plt.fill_between( np.arange(0,len(l1)), a_seq, l1, alpha=0.2)
plt.show()
```

#### Fill between a_seq and l1

[image: Fill between a_seq and l1]

```
plt.plot(np.arange(0,len(a_seq)),a_seq)
plt.plot(l1)
plt.plot(l2)
plt.fill_between( np.arange(0,len(l1)), a_seq, l2, alpha=0.2)
plt.show()
```

#### Fill between a_seq and l2

[image: Fill between a_seq and l2]